# jQuery-based image carousel or horizontal scroller control for iPad swipe event?

Tags: jquery-mobile, carousel, swipe

I am writing a web-based application for Safari on the iPad and am looking for a jQuery-based solution for horizontal navigation.  I've found several examples, but I want to create/use a horizontal carousel containing images hopefully stored in a `<ul>`.  The selected image would be enlarged and in the middle of the carousel while the other images before and after the selected image would still be visible but smaller.  A person could then swipe in either direction (no mouse click) to scroll left/right (or up/down through the `<ul>`).

I explored jQueryMobile and jQTouch and found many examples of using swipe but would like to avoid having to create this from scratch to address my requirements described above, if possible.

I've also found several good jQuery slider plugins like [Swipe](http://bradbirdsall.com/post/10687800055/swipe-1-0-a-lightweight-mobile-slider) and [Flexslider](http://flex.madebymufffin.com/) but I guess I'm being picky as I want to be able to preview the next images, as well as use something like the momentum property to scroll faster if a quick swipe.

I also found a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808389/jqtouch-swipe-event-carousel) topic posted on Stack Overflow.

Any help, pointers or advice is appreciated.